# Limit characters/digits entered into InputField

Tags: front-end, string-manipulation, inputfield

When using `InputField`, whether setting the input type as a `Number` or `String`, is there a way to limit the number of characters or digits allowed in the box?

`FieldSize` appears to set the physical size of the input box, but accommodates larger numbers of digits/characters, simply by enlarging the box in the vertical direction with additional lines, delimiting the end of the line with `\` or similar character.

For instance, if I want to limit the input to 5 digits/characters, is this possible, and if so, how is this done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is some code I have for entering a **8 digit** id number. *So this is "out of the box" as is.* If you enter more than **8 digits** the extra characters are immediately deleted. You can modify to suit your purpose:

```
InputField[Dynamic[id, (id = Which[
      StringMatchQ[#, DigitCharacter ..] && StringLength[#] >= 8,StringTake[#, 8],
      StringMatchQ[#, DigitCharacter ..], #,
      True, ""]) &], String, ContinuousAction -> True, FieldSize -> 8]
```

Suggested modification is to remove the digit character constraint if that is more applicable to your needs. The above is for strings of course.

The animated GIF doesn't really do a good job of showing me trying to enter a 9th digit but anyway:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work on my system (v. 10.0.0).  The characters are deleted immediately upon entering them.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork you're limited to 8 digit characters

Comment: Ah yes... digits, not letters or strings.  Fine.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yes strings, but digit characters. if you enter a non digit character the first to tests fail which leaves you with `True, ""` in the `Which`. Obviously you can remove the digit character constraint to enable any string character to be entered.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch  This is great, and solves the `String` half of this problem.  Is there a `Number` version of this for that half of the problem?

Comment: @iwantmyphd for numbers it is more complicated and probably a separate question. How do you want to handle decimals, how do you want to handle exponents etc etc. I'd suggest asking a separate question with all of the specifics mapped out in detail because it requires a lot more planning

Comment: @iwantmyphd if you want to play around with making a version that works with numbers my starting point would be to try something using `IntegerDigits` and `FromDigits` in the function that tests the input.

Comment: @Kuba You are welcome to submit this as an answer.

Comment: @iwantmyphd ok, done :)